# PHP - Why object datetime attribut is updated with my cloned object datetime attribut?

Tags: php, datetime, clone

In my project, I've an object Absence, which has lot of attributes including a "dateDebut" attribute.

In a function, I process this object to get some information. And in this function I happen to have to add a day to the dateTime like this

`$processAbsence->setDateDebut($processAbsence->getDateDebut()->modify('+1 day'));`

My goal is obviously not to modify the initial object. This is why I cloned the object before:

```php
    public function getNotWorkingDays(Absence $absence)
    {
        //$absence is my original object. I clone it to not apply some modifications on it.
        $processAbsence = (clone $absence)

        while($this->canAbsenceProgress($processAbsence))
        {
           $processAbsence = $this->doAbsenceProgress($processAbsence);
        }

      //...
   }

       private function doAbsenceProgress(Absence $absence)
    {
        // Here too, I cloned the previous cloned object, I make some modifications on it and return it
        $processAbsence = (clone $absence);

        if ('matin' == $processAbsence->getMomentDebut()) {
            $processAbsence->setMomentDebut('après-midi');
        } else {
            $processAbsence->setDateDebut($processAbsence->getDateDebut()->modify('+1 day'));
            $processAbsence->setMomentDebut('matin');
        }

        return $processAbsence;
    }
```

But when I dump my `$absence` object, I can see that the `$absence->getDateDebut()` has been changed just like the cloned object should be ...

I do not understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

> When an object is cloned, PHP will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.

As shown in the docs, you'll probably need to give your Absence class a `__clone` method inside of which, you'll need to explicitly clone the properties that are references to datetime objects so you end up with clones of those as well instead of pointers to the same objects:

```
class Absence 
{
    public $dateDebut;

    function __clone()
    {
        // Force a copy of this->dateDebut, otherwise
        // it will point to same object.
        $this->dateDebut= clone $this->dateDebut;
    }
}
```